# How do I create batch file to rename large number of files in a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, cmd

I'd like to rename a large number of files within a folder on a WinXP system, preferably using a batch file.

The files are currently named like this:

> Vacation2010 001.jpg
>   Vacation2010 002.jpg
>   Vacation2010 003.jpg

And I'd like to change them to:

> December 001.jpg
>   December 002.jpg
>   December 003.jpg

How can I perform this operation??

Comment: You may like [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/), which I used for a few years, right up until I stopped using Windows at home.  It has a batch rename interface to handle this situation without programming, and is just well worth the cost, all around.

Comment: @Roger Also Bulk Rename Utility (http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk)  is a very good tool and it is free.

Answer (score 27):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=Vacation2010
SET new=December
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

What this does is it loops over all .jpg files in the folder where the batch file is located and replaces the Vacation2010 with December inside the filenames.

Comment: To rename only selected files, can we specify file names as AB.jpg, ABC.jpg, ABCD.jpg like that?

Answer (score 11):

```
dir /b *.jpg >file.bat
```

This will give you lines such as:

> Vacation2010 001.jpg
>   Vacation2010 002.jpg
>   Vacation2010 003.jpg

Edit file.bat in your [favorite Windows](http://www.textpad.com/) [text-editor](http://www.vim.org/), doing the equivalent of:

```
s/Vacation2010(.+)/rename "&" "December \1"/
```

That's a [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/); many editors support them, but none that come default with Windows (as far as I know).  You can also get a command line tool such as sed or perl which can take the exact syntax I have above, after escaping for the command line.

The resulting lines will look like:

> rename "Vacation2010 001.jpg" "December 001.jpg"
>   rename "Vacation2010 002.jpg" "December 002.jpg"
>   rename "Vacation2010 003.jpg" "December 003.jpg"

You may recognize these lines as rename commands, one per file from the original listing. ;)  Run that batch file in cmd.exe.

Comment: That /b flag to dir is incredibly useful, isn't it?

Comment: @Jim: Not as useful as *ls* under cygwin! :)  dir /s is also underappreciated.

Comment: It's orrible that an operating system needs such a trick to simply rename a set of files, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

you can do this easily without manual editing or using fancy text editors. Here's a vbscript.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder="c:\test"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    If objFS.GetExtensionName(strFile) = "jpg" Then    
        strFileName = strFile.Name
        If InStr(strFileName,"Vacation2010") > 0 Then           
            strNewFileName = Replace(strFileName,"Vacation2010","December")
            strFile.Name = strNewFileName
        End If 
    End If  
Next
```

save as myscript.vbs and

```
C:\test> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO off & SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "_dir=" REM Must finish with '\'
SET "_ext=jpg"
SET "_toEdit=Vacation2010"
SET "_with=December"
FOR %%f IN ("%_dir%*.%_ext%") DO (
    CALL :modifyString "%_toEdit%" "%_with%" "%%~Nf" fileName 
    RENAME "%%f" "!fileName!%%~Xf"
)
GOTO end

:modifyString what with in toReturn
    SET "__in=%~3"
    SET "__in=!__in:%~1=%~2!"
    IF NOT "%~4" == "" (
        SET %~4=%__in%
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %__in%
    )
    EXIT /B

:end
```

This script allows you to change the name of all the files that contain `Vacation2010` with the same name, but with `December` instead of `Vacation2010`.

If you copy and paste the code, you have to save the `.bat` in the same folder of the photos.
If you want to save the script in another directory [E.G. you have a favorite folder for the utilities] you have to change the value of `_dir` with the path of the photos.

If you have to do the same work for other photos [or others files changig `_ext`] you have to change the value of `_toEdit` with the string you want to change [or erase] and the value of `_with` with the string you want to put instead of `_toEdit` [`SET "_with="` if you simply want to erase the string specified in `_toEdit`].

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a batch file, just do this from powershell :

```
powershell -C "gci | % {rni $_.Name ($_.Name -replace 'Vacation2010', 'December')}"
```