# Batch File Rename(Timestamp removal)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have done some research and not found very much and what I have found I could not get to work. Here is one thing that I have found here on stackoverflow. [cmd - batch file rename - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/batch-file-rename)

I use a big cannon copier to scan files into a folder on a network drive. I name the file before it is scanned and the copier puts a timestamp on the end of the file which looks like "_20141021165008" and I would like to remove the timestamp when the file is sent to the computer. The files are scanned to one of three locations and I would like to have each of them do the same thing.

This is what it looks like coming from the copier:

```
001-Bob_(1-100)_20141021165008
002-Bob_(1-25)_20141021170515
1-67676_Ex.Sheets_20141021172043
```

and this is what I would like them to look like:

```
001-Bob_(1-100)
002-Bob_(1-25)
1-67676_Ex.Sheets
```

Also, the names and numbers change all of the time.
I have it so that file extensions are not visible. But the files are 99.9% of the time .PDF

What I would like to do is:

- Have timestamp automatically removed when the files arrive in the folder.
- not rename a file more than once so that I don't lose any of the file name.

I have a batch file that removes the last 12 characters of the file name and I created a shortcut to it and use a keyboard shortcut but it doesn't work on everything, isn't fully automated, and I have to reset the shortcut every few days because it just stops working...

Running Win7 Pro 64x

Thank you to anyone that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, but not quite what you asked for. And the command can be run as many times as you want without risk of changing the name of an already renamed file.

```
ren *_*.pdf *_.pdf
```

The above command will give the following results with the files you listed in your question:

```
001-Bob_(1-100)_20141021165008.pdf    -->  001-Bob_(1-100)_.pdf
002-Bob_(1-25)_20141021170515.pdf     -->  002-Bob_(1-25)_.pdf
1-67676_Ex.Sheets_20141021172043.pdf  -->  1-67676_Ex.Sheets_.pdf
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation of why the above command works.

Comment: Where is this behavior of `ren` documented?

Comment: +1. News to me so I obviously need to review the current command set.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - See the link in updated answer. As far as I know, the behavior is not properly documented by MicroSoft. I ran a bunch of experiments to reverse engineer the behavior.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Reviewing MicroSoft documentation will not be of much help. You should take a look at the link in the updated answer.

Comment: EDIT - Changed the source mask to `*_*.pdf` so that it only renames files that contain an underscore.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you I changed it up just a bit and put

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %A in ('dir /b *_*_*.*') do ren "%A_%B_%C%D" "%A_%B%D"
```

This reads the output of the dir command. It won't work on files with more than two underscores. If you need that just say so. In a batch file change %A etc to %%A.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "target_folder=c:\some_dir"
pushd "%target_folder%" 2>nul

rem  --Remove comments in case of network drive.
rem net use h: %target_folder%
rem pushd h:

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*_2014*) do (
    set filename=%%~na
    set newname=!filename:~0,-14!
    rem --Remove the echo if the new file name is OK
    echo ren "%%~nxa" "!newname!%%~xa"

)
endlocal
endlocal
```