# Rename multiple files using windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, file-rename

I have several files with the name format **dbo.table_name.sql** and 
i want to rename them into **table_name.1.tbl** how to do it using **windows cmd prompt**?

i have tried `ren *.sql *.1.tbl` but it only rename it to **dbo.table_name.1.tbl**
still not able to remove **dbo.** here..
also tried `ren dbo.*.sql *.1.tbl` still not luck :(

Comment: `ren` can change the tail end of the filenames, but you'll need a for loop for the beginning.  See the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/batch-file-rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file like this would work.

@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in (dbo*.sql) do (
  set "name=%%~nF"
  ren "!name!.sql" "!name:dbo.=!.tbl"
)