# cmd batch rename using string or tirm

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I have a couple .pdf files with with the following:

```
filename_garbage.pdf
```

I would like to rename the files by removing the _garbage in one fell swoop to

```
filename.pdf
```

The file name is unique as is the _garbage which is also a variable length.

Ie:

```
123456_1.pdf
789012_1000.pdf
345678_garbage.pdf
```

rename to :

```
123456.pdf
789012.pdf
345678.pdf
```

I know it is a multi-step process, but so far not having any success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all files in a directory with a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/rename-all-files-in-a-directory-with-a-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b "*_*.*"') do ren "%%a_%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
```

Suggest you `echo` the `ren` commands for verification purposes before applying the script in anger.

If run directly from the prompt, reduce `%%n` to `%n`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista or newer? Use PowerShell. It's a one step process in a reasonably modern language.

```
gci | ren -NewName { $_ -replace '_.*(?=\.)' }
```

which is short for

```
Get-ChildItem .\ | Rename-Item -NewName { $_ -replace '_.*(?=\.)' }
```

and the replace pattern is a regular expression which matches an underscore `_` followed by anything, up to a dot `.`, and it replaces with nothing. So in your examples it replaces `_1`, `_1000`, `_garbage`.