# Batch script to find file and rename it

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename, windows-console

Need a batch script that recursively searches the whole C: drive for a specific file by file name and then renames the file

This is what I have so far. It appears to find the file but then it does not rename it.

```
@echo off

for /r "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "C:\test.pdf"') do (ren "%%i" test2.pdf)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all files in a directory with a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/rename-all-files-in-a-directory-with-a-windows-batch-script)

Comment: `for /F  "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d "C:\test.pdf"') do …` rather than `for /r`

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2003 and later (i.e. anything after Windows XP 32 bit) provide the `where.exe`,it matches all types of files.
It will even accept wildcards.
Try `where /?` for help.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
Set Location=C:\
Set PatternName=test.pdf
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Where /R %Location% /F %PatternName%') do (
    set MyFilename=%%F 
    ren !MyFilename! "test2.pdf"
)
pause
```