# Rename extension by batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to rename the extension for multiple files at once using batch.
However I am not sure I am going in the right direction. I am learning batch scripting.

Example ABCDEFRGGT.word.docx --> ABCDEFRGGT.docx

I have tried this so far but it does not work.

```
cd /d C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\rename
ren '*.word.docx' *.docx
```

Comment: Not a solution, but: replace `'` by `"`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all files in a directory with a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/rename-all-files-in-a-directory-with-a-windows-batch-script)

Comment: Just as a comment: you are _not_ "renaming the extension". The files have the same extension after renamed: `.docx`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and its variable reference `~` modifiers to split off file name extensions, like this:

```cmd
for %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\Documents\rename\*.word.docx") do (
    rem // `%%~nI` returns the file name with the (last) extension removed:
    for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        rem /* `%%~nJ` returns the file name with the next-to-last extension removed too;
        rem    `%%~xI` returns the original (last) file name extension: */
        ren "%%~I" "%%~nJ%%~xI"
    )
)
```

Comment: @user3758867, you don't need to include your `cd` command if you include it within the first set of parentheses. Here it is as a single batch file line, `For %%I In ("%UserProfile%\Documents\rename\*.word.docx") Do For %%J In ("%%~nI") Do Ren "%%~I" "%%~nJ%%~xI"`.

Answer (score 0):

**1 method.**

```
rename *.word.docx *.
rename *.word *.docx
```

**2 method.**

```
rename *.word.docx ??????????????????????????????.docx
```