# HOW to copy/rename all files in a directory in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

My question is similar to [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383032/rename-all-files-in-a-directory-with-a-windows-batch-script), but I would like to give the new files, (for copy), an odd number.

It should work in a `cmd.exe` window under Windows 10.

In a directory I have:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

...and would like to copy these files to:

```
_1.txt
_3.txt
_5.txt
```

I have tried this, but without success:

```
@echo off                       
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
set COUNTER=-1                   
for %%F in (*.txt) do (         
    set /A C = %COUNTER% + 2      
    rem echo %C%                      
    copy %%F _%C%.txt             
    set COUNTER = %C%             
)
```

Can someone tell my why this do not work? The `%C%` is always empty.

Comment: check the typo in your script, it's in the line `set COUNTER = %C%`,there should not be any spaces around the equal sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be opened a command prompt window, ran `set /?` and read the output usage help. It explains the syntax to (re)define environment variables. There are no spaces around `=`. See also: [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) There is also explained when and how to use [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on an **IF** and a **FOR** example. It is also described that the current values of environment variables should be referenced within an **arithmetic expression** with using just the variable names without using `%` or `!` around the variable names. An **arithmetic expression** is the argument string after option `/A` of command **SET**.

There can be also executed in the command prompt window `for /?` for getting output the usage help of command **FOR** which is obviously needed too.

There are some important facts not described in the helps of command **FOR** and **SET** which are important on copying (or renaming or deleting or modifying) files in a directory with file extension kept and so matched also by the wildcard pattern.

1. **FOR** processes the list of matching file system entries which changes on each iteration of the loop because of the file copy operation which is very problematic here. For more details see: [At which point does `for` or `for /R` enumerate the directory (tree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975093/) The solution is getting first loaded all the wildcard pattern matching file names into the memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file before starting the copy operation loop.
2. Enabled delayed variable expansion results in parsing a command line a second time by `cmd.exe` after **loop** variable references like `%%F` are replaced by the string assigned to the loop variable. An exclamation mark in a file name is therefore interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference. An exclamation mark is removed on being the last `!` on odd number of `!` in file name and everything between two `!` in a file name is replaced by the value of the referenced environment variable respectively is removed from file name on no such environment variable exists at all. The result of this unwanted file name change caused by enabled delayed expansion is a not found file or a by mistake wrong selected file for the copy operation. See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Here is a batch file code which copies all non-hidden files with file extension `.txt` even on containing on or more `!` in file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=-1"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.txt /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set /A Counter+=2
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    copy /B /Y "!FileName!" "_!Counter!.txt" >nul
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

There is started by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file one more command process in background with using `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` specified on the **FOR /F** command line appended as additional arguments. There is executed for that reason with Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir *.txt /A-D-H /B /ON 2>nul
```

The internal command **DIR** of in background started `cmd.exe` searches now

- in the current directory as defined by the process starting `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file which can be any directory and not necessarily the directory containing the batch file
- for just non-hidden files or non-hidden links to files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden) including files with read-only attribute set
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.txt` in long or short 8.3 file name
- and outputs in bare format just the file names because of option `/B`
- in alphabetical order by name because of option `/ON`.

An error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on no matching file system entry found is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The *Windows Command Processor* processing the batch file captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process. Once **DIR** finished resulting in **close** of the background `cmd.exe` because of option `/c`, the internal command **FOR** of the batch file processing `cmd.exe` starts the processing of the list of file names which is loaded now into the memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. The file copy operations in same directory do not change anymore the file names list processed by **FOR**.

The **FOR /F** option `delims=` defines an empty list of delimiters to turn off the default line splitting behavior on normal spaces and horizontal tabs to get the full file name in a line assigned to the specified loop variable `I` and not just the first space/tab separated string as by default.

The **FOR /F** option `eol=|` defines the vertical bar as end of line character replacing the default `;` which prevents ignoring a file name beginning with a semicolon. The Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) describes which characters are not allowed in file names on Windows file systems like NTFS, FAT32 or exFAT. One of those characters should be used as end of line character.

It is necessary to assign first the file name with file extension to an environment variable and increment the value of the environment variable `Counter` by two. Then delayed variable expansion is enabled for copying the file with referencing the file name assigned to the environment variable `FileName` and the value of the `Counter` environment variable. The previous environment must be restored next with the command **ENDLOCAL** as otherwise a stack overflow could occur during the copy operations. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** with a full description what happens on each execution of **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** in memory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

**NOTE:**

It would be a very good idea to copy the files into a different directory than the current directory like the parent directory of the current directory by using the command line:

```
copy /B /Y "!FileName!" "..\_!Counter!!FileExt!" >nul
```

The code above is still a problem if the current directory contains `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, ... but also already `_1.txt`, `_3.txt`, `_5.txt`, ... from a previous execution of the batch file. Copying the files into a different directory would avoid that problem as well as the usage of the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Counter=-1"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.txt /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /X "_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.txt"') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    set /A Counter+=2
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    copy /B /Y "!FileName!" "_!Counter!.txt" >nul
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The command **FINDSTR** is used for filtering out all file names of which entire name is matched case-insensitive by the regular expression which searches for an underscore followed by one or more digits and next a literally interpreted dot and the string `txt`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have a typo in your script, just try to remove the spaces around the equal sign in this line `set COUNTER = %C%` and better to add double quotes around `%%F` and `_!C!.txt` to handle file names with spaces correctly, and also change `%C%` to `!C!` to enable delayed expansion inside the loop!

so check this out :

```
@echo off                       
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
set COUNTER=-1                   
for %%F in (*.txt) do (         
      set /A C=%COUNTER%+2      
      rem echo !C!                      
      copy "%%F" "_!C!.txt"             
      set COUNTER=!C!             
)
```

Comment: you don't even need the `c` variable. Increase the `counter` directly: `set /a counter+=2` (and `copy"%%F" "_!counter!.txt"` Also it might be a good idea to not rename files already starting with `_`: `for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt ^| findstr /bv "_"') do (

Answer (score 1):

Here is what your code should have looked like:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Counter=-1"
For %%G In ("*.txt") Do (
    Set /A Counter += 2
    Rem Echo !Counter!
    Copy /Y "%%G" "_!Counter!%%~xG"
)
EndLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` command is used to enable delayed variable expansion with `!` instead of `%` for variable access, but you are still using `%` for variable access in your script. You should use `!` instead of `%` if you intend to use delayed variable expansion.

There is a space before and after the equals sign in the `set COUNTER = %C%` line, which is incorrect. Batch script variable assignment should not have spaces around the equals sign.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set COUNTER=-1
    for %%F in (*.txt) do (
        set /A C=!COUNTER! + 2
        rem echo !C!
        copy %%F _!C!.txt
        set COUNTER=!C!
)
```