# Copying and renaming resource files with script

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently working on a project with multiple language options. I have loads of resource files with my first language and want to copy these files and add some text to them using some sort of batch script in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

From within VS it will be hard to achieve. There are many standalone tools to edit .resx files separately (like http://resx.sourceforge.net or http://resxmanager.com). Great help when translation gthe files, but I do not know any capable of scripting/batching the job.

RESX are simple XML files, so I think you'd be quicker to write simple console app to load the XMLs via standard C#/Perl/Ruby/Python libraries, patch the texts, and write them back to files instead of searching for a scriptable tool, but maybe I'm wrong. I'd be happy to see such tool too! :)

-- edit:

With pure .bat batch files, it may be hard, because the Windows Console simply lacks proper string-replace commands and you have to use some tricky commands like [see the BAT here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3811991/717732).. At least small tool like grep or sed would be handy, and the script would be 100% more flexible.

You can rather easily do it with PowerShell, CygWin, Ruby, etc or even the JScript/VBScript that you should already have installed along with your Windows. [See here for a such a script in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809876/717732). It scans only a specific directly witout subfolders, but you can easily mix it with [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gstemp/archive/2004/08/10/212113.aspx) to get recursive directory walking. Btw. VBS is kept in files of such extension: `myscript.vbs` and may be simply double-clicked or simply run just like .bat or .exe files.

All of this however are more like typical programming.. If you have some complex renames to do and if you dont have any Python/Ruby/blargh at hand, I'd recommend just writing it in C# as the code will be friendlier.

Comment: Could I create a batch file that goes through all the folders in my project, finds the ones with the .resx file ending, copies it and rename it?

Example: UserControlOne.aspx.resx -> UserControlOne.aspx.resx +  UserControlOne.aspx.en.US.resx

Comment: see the edits above :) all links point to working scripts, so you will probably get it working fast.