# windows batch rename files with padded numeric file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Back in DOS 5 (LOL) I thought I understood batch files, but I'm at a loss.

I have a series of files:

```
disc51.mp3
disc52.mp3
disc53.mp3
disc54.mp3
disc55.mp3
disc56.mp3
disc57.mp3
disc58.mp3
disc59.mp3
disc510.mp3
disc511.mp3
```

...etc

I need them to be renamed:

```
disc501.mp3
disc502.mp3
disc503.mp3
disc504.mp3
disc505.mp3
disc506.mp3
disc507.mp3
disc508.mp3
disc509.mp3
disc510.mp3
disc511.mp3
```

So I need to only rename the first 9 files in the sequence and do so by adding a '0' between char 5 and 6. How do I do this?

This is my first stab which assumes that each file will begin with 'disc5'. However, I'd like something more generic, ie. that would work properly regardless of the initial naming convention. The only thing I'd like to assume is that after that 'name' the numbers would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, etc.

```
echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%G IN (*.MP3) DO ( call :strlen %%G)
exit /b
)
:strlen
  set myvar=%~n1
  rem now compute the length of the string
  set #=!myvar!
  set length=0
  :loop
  if defined # (
    rem shorten string by one character
    set #=!#:~1!
    rem increment the string count variable %length%
    set /A length += 1
    rem repeat until string is null
    goto loop
  )
  rem assuming file name starts with disc. I'd like to make this a more general case
  if %length%==6 ren %1 !myvar:~0,5!0!myvar:~5,1!.mp3
  exit /b
```

Comment: [How do I create batch file to rename large number of files in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3808001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do ren "%1%%i.mp3" "%10%%i.mp3"
```

Previous Batch file requires the initial name in the first parameter, for example:

```
test.bat disc5
```

You may also use previous method directly in the command-line:

```
for /L %i in (1,1,9) do ren "disc5%i.mp3" "disc50%i.mp3"
```

Comment: Man, I love Stackoverflow. This is the kind of thing I do about once every 3 years and totally space on everything beyond the basics. CHEERS!