# Batch rename and copy multiple files in Windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-v5.1

I have a large number of files with names like this in a same folder:

- myPic_fr.png
- myPic_it.png
- myPic_gr.png

I want to rename them to:

- myPic_fr_1080.png
- myPic_it_1080.png
- myPic_gr_1080.png

Then copy them to a new folder like this:

- ../fr/myPic_fr_1080.png
- ../it/myPic_it_1080.png
- ../gr/myPic_gr_1080.png

How to create a batch script or powershell script to do that job?

Edit:
I tried this batch script code to do the rename job ([Thanks @RoXX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3811991/10100062)):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET oldPart=.png
SET newPart=_1080.png
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.png') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%oldPart%=%newPart%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

But for the "copy" part I don't know how to do it! Maybe need Regex?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to rename them just in the destination folder, or in both places?

Comment: I'd try reading the documentation first: [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem), [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item6) & [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) and then make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code, explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you.

Comment: in both places.

Comment: You way over coded the batch file.  Read the last section of the help file for the `FOR` command.  It is super easy to strip the file extension from the file name without having to do string replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample tree before

```
> tree /f
    myPic_fr.png
    myPic_gr.png
    myPic_it.png
```

running this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\11\SO_52760856.ps1
Get-ChildItem *_*.png | Where-Object BaseName -match '^.*_([^_]{2})$' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $Country=$Matches[1]
    $NewName=$_.BaseName+"_1080"+$_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
    if (!(Test-Path $Country)){MD $Country|Out-Null}
    Copy-Item  $NewName (Join-Path $Country $newName)  
  }
```

and the tree after

```
> tree /f
│   myPic_fr_1080.png
│   myPic_gr_1080.png
│   myPic_it_1080.png
│
├───fr
│       myPic_fr_1080.png
│
├───gr
│       myPic_gr_1080.png
│
└───it
        myPic_it_1080.png
```

Comment: Thanks very much @lotpings  Just one more thing, how to match a file name in this format myPic_02_fr.png ?

Comment: To avoid problems when running the script mutiple times I chose a RegEx to select the country which only expects **one** underscore. The way @Esperento57 uses avoids this by selecting the last underscore delimited token. I'll modifiy my RegEx to be u - nspecific on the numer of underscores in  a .minute - **DONE**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again 

Answer (score 0):

This is far from optimal, but you could try something like this:

```
foreach ($pic in (Get-ChildItem *.png -Name)) {
    # delete "myPic_" and ".png" to get the destination-folder from the filename
    $destFolder = ($pic -replace "myPic_", "") -replace "`.png", ""
    # replace ".png" with "_1080.png" to create the new filename
    $destName = $pic -replace ".png", "_1080.png"

    Copy-Item "$pic" "$destFolder\$destName"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test" -file -Filter "?*_?*.png" | %{

$NewName="{0}_1080{1}" -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension
$NewDir="{0}\{1}" -f $_.DirectoryName, ($_.BaseName -split "_")[-1]
$NewPath="{0}\{1}" -f $NewDir, $NewName

New-Item $NewDir -ItemType Directory -Force
Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $NewPath -Force -Recurse
Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $NewName
}
```